# Circular ViewPager Indicator like Galaxy Tab2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hii i  want to make a circular  `ViewPager` Indicator same exartly like `Samsung Galaxy Tab2`,I have 5 `Frgments` in my `Viewpager`  you can navigate in a circular way like this
**1->2->3->4->5->1 so on .** is anybody has any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: use this library for jake wharton its contains what u need to do https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: No this is not working in my case i have already tried,as i mentioned here i am navigating in circular way so this lib is not applicable fro my app.because its adding infinite indicator dots in my screen.

Comment: @Ohh It will be helpful if you post sample code for circular viewpager indicator.Here is my question for circular viewpager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421341/andriodviewpager-circular-swipe-first-page-to-last-page-or-last-page-to-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  i solved my question by using  setting  indicator images  dynamically based on the pages  of  viewpagers with out using any  external  library..

Comment: Could you please share your solution? Thanks

Comment: just check the current page and add the dots or images based on that.as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can to it very easily with the new TabLayout. For full description check [this sample example](https://medium.com/dailyrounds-engineering/simple-on-boarding-screen-in-andorid-d31f8a472f1e#.bwhzcbt6u)

Comment: Thanks i have achieved it some other way  3 years before .may be it would help others.